# Windows Server 2003 call to secedit within a batch script generates "C:\Program" on system reboot

Tags: windows-services, batch-file, windows-server-2003

In executing
    `secedit /configure /db %~1\tomcat.sdb" /cfg %~1\2003.inf" /log %~1\dtomcat.log" /quiet`

where
`%~1 == C:\Program Files\myDirectory\mySubDirectory\mySuperSubDirectory`

a file titled "C:\Program" is generated and within the file is the output for calling
`secedit /?`

I am curious as to why this is occuring because it makes it quite difficult to start certain services after an installation of a new product, for instance a PostGres windows service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be missing quotes in a couple of places:

```
secedit /configure /db "%~1\tomcat.sdb" /cfg "%~1\2003.inf" /log "%~1\dtomcat.log" /quiet
                       ^                     ^                   ^
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issue quite effectively.  This is what happens when I keep switching between *nix and windows

Comment: @Joey: You can backslash-escape spaces instead of using quotes. (Just sayin')

Comment: You can, indeed. But I guess you will always use quotes if your command line involves variables that could contain spaces. You won't do a search-and-replace for spaces in there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose the pathname in quotes:

> "C:\Program Files\myDirectory\mySubDirectory\mySuperSubDirectory"

The space in "Program Files" is treated as a delimiter.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however this solution here failed because of the extra ' " ' at the end of mySuperSubDirectory.  +1 regardless :)

Comment: @Woot4Moo - Ah - well the answer is the missing quote before each % as system PAUSE points out.